# Weird typings error for es6 promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise, typescript-typings

Code

```
getToken(authCode: string): Promise<Token> {
    return fetch(tokenUrl, { method: "POST" }).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
        if (json["error"]) {
            return Promise.reject(json);
        }
        return new Token(json);
    });
}
```

Tsc(2.0.6) reports error:

```
xxx.ts(135,81): error TS2345: Argument of type '(json: any) => Promise<never> | Token' is not assignable to p
arameter of type '(value: any) => PromiseLike<never>'.                                                               
  Type 'Promise<never> | Token' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<never>'.                                      
    Type 'Token' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<never>'.                                                     
      Property 'then' is missing in type 'Token'.
```

Tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

Typings for promise is defined in `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts`

---

However, if I do not return rejected Promise:

```
getToken(authCode: string): Promise<Token> {
    return fetch(tokenUrl, { method: "POST" }).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
        return new Token(json);
    });
}
```

There will be no errors. So how can I return a rejected promise?

Answer (score 2):

You don't return the rejected promise, you simply throw an error which will cause the promise to be rejected:

```
getToken(authCode: string): Promise<Token> {
    return fetch(tokenUrl, { method: "POST" }).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
        if (json["error"]) {
            throw new Error(json["error"]);
        }

        return new Token(json);
    });
}
```

Comment: Actually, I use `throw json["json"]`, since `json["error"]` is an object not string. But I just don't understand what is the problem when I return the rejected promise.

Comment: The function you're passing to `then` should return a value and not a promise. If it all goes well it returns the value, otherwise throws an error. The `then` function return the `Promise`.

Comment: @Kevin: The problem is that your code returns `Promise<never>` in the error case, and `Token` object in normal case, so the inferred return type for `json => ...` callback is `Token | Promise<never>`, which prevents type inference from doing anything sensible for the `then()` method. You have to be consistent - you can either return `Promise.resolve(new Token(json))` in normal case and `Promise.reject(...)`in error case, or return an object and throw exception as in the code in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for answering an old question, but I think you need to wrap `return new Token(json)` with `Promise.resolve()`

```
getToken(authCode: string): Promise<Token> {
  return fetch(tokenUrl, { method: "POST" })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      if (json["error"]) {
        return Promise.reject(json);
      }
      // See this
      return Promise.resolve(new Token(json));
    });
}
```